# Data scraping multiple array creation and ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

We're trying to scrape the course names, qualification and duration of the course and store each in a separate array. With the below we pull all of that, but it seems to be in random order, with some parts potentially ordered by page etc. Wondering if anybody is able to help.

```
require 'mechanize'


mechanize = Mechanize.new
@duration_array = []
@qual_array = []
@courses_array = []

page = mechanize.get('http://search.ucas.com/search/results?Vac=2&AvailableIn=2016&IsFeatherProcessed=True&page=1&providerids=41')


page.search('div.courseinfoduration').each do |x|
puts x.text.strip
page.search('div.courseinfooutcome').each do |y|
puts y.text.strip

end

while next_page_link = page.at('.pager a[text()=">"]')
  page = mechanize.get(next_page_link['href'])

page.search('div.courseinfoduration').each do |x|
    name = x
    @duration_array.push(name)
    puts x.text.strip
  end
end
while next_page_link = page.at('.pager a[text()=">"]')
  page = mechanize.get(next_page_link['href'])

page.search('div.courseinfooutcome').each do |y|
    name = y
    @qual_array.push(name)
    puts y.text.strip
  end
end
page.search('div.coursenamearea h4').each do |h4|
puts h4.text.strip

end

while next_page_link = page.at('.pager a[text()=">"]')
  page = mechanize.get(next_page_link['href'])

page.search('div.coursenamearea h4').each do |h4|
    name = h4.text
    @courses_array.push(name)
    puts h4.text.strip
  end
end
end
```

Comment: what's your question here?

Comment: Wondering if anyone can help with ordering the output. So that either all of the courses are spat out, then the duration, then qualification, or if the duration and qualification for each course can be paired with the course name. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: This is a partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37681359/128421